# filled / open circle by group

Tags: r

I have trouble making a filled / open circle plot by group.

My data looks like:

```
Body_weight  Gender
50            M
60            M 
55            M
45            F
43            F
42            F
```

I want to plot the male weights in filled circle and the female weights in open.

I tried:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Gender, y=Body_weight))+
 geom_point(aes(fill=Gender))
```

But, this only gives filled circles for both gender.
I have no idea why this does not work.

`geom_point(aes(shape=Gender))` works and gives a circle / triangle plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aesthetic "fill" does not determine if the point is filled with colour or not, but fills it with a different colour for each gender. The way to do what you want is using "shape" and mapping the shapes to open and closed circle instead of the default circle/triangle you get. To do this you need to use `scale_shape_manual`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Gender, y=Body_weight)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape=Gender)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 21))
```

Have a look at http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape for other shapes available
[image]

Comment: Konvas: Thank you so much for your very prompt help! This is exactly what I wanted. I learned how "fill" works. Thanks a lot again.